# Converting *.raw to *.tiff

Tags: c, dcraw, libraw

There was such a problem. Requires conversion of `*.RAW` files received the camera `4K NDVI CAMERA` for `GitUp G3`.

I use `libraw.h`, 
which contains `dcraw.c`. She works with the `GitUp Git2` camera format.

My file she does not recognize it and deduces

> Unsupported file format or not RAW file

I also tried the `raw2dng` utility, but also there is an

> Unsupported file format

Help please find a way to convert this `*.RAW` file.

I attach the file (https://yadi.sk/d/sdHHY4jw3aj4Ga).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Cameras all have different RAW formats. You need a convertor that supports your specific model. [Darktable apparently doesn't](https://www.darktable.org/resources/camera-support/)

Comment: libraw can list the cameras it supports using `LibRaw::cameraCount()` and `LibRaw::cameraList()`

Comment: @Pelipap,  I checked. My camera is not listed. Therefore, alternatives are required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. For this, I added support for the camera in classes libraw library:

> libraw_cxx.cpp
>
> dcraw_common.cpp
>
> dcraw.c

Here are the parameters:

```
{24000000, 4000, 3000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x94, 0, 0, "GITUP", "G3DUO 4:3"},
{18016000, 4000, 2250, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x94, 0, 0, "GITUP", "G3DUO 16:9"}
```

After that, the project was re-compiled and now dcraw_emu can convert raw to tiff for this camera!